# Serve text instead of images - Trivia javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working code of a 10 questions' trivia game with a timer (html, javascript, css), that serves images from a folder, and has 4 options for answers.

I want to **serve text questions instead of images**. Can you assist?

I have manipulated severely the css and html code (and a little the js) to make it cleaner and simpler, using ideas from codepen and the internet. However, my javascript skills are very limited.

```js
(function() {
  const playButton = document.querySelector("#play");
  const letsstartButton = document.querySelector("#lets-start");
  const playagainButton = document.querySelector("#play-again");
  const howToPlayButton = document.querySelector("#how-to-play-button");
  const closeHowToButton = document.querySelector("#close-how-to");
  const howToPlayScreen = document.querySelector(".how-to-play-screen");
  const mainScreen = document.querySelector(".main-screen");
  const triviaScreen = document.querySelector(".trivia-screen");
  const resultScreen = document.querySelector(".result-screen");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", startTrivia);
  letsstartButton.addEventListener("click", startTrivia);
  playagainButton.addEventListener("click", startTrivia);

  howToPlayButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    howToPlayScreen.classList.remove("hidden");
    mainScreen.classList.add("hidden");
  });

  closeHowToButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    howToPlayScreen.classList.add("hidden");
    mainScreen.classList.remove("hidden");
  });

  const questionLength = 10;
  let questionIndex = 0;
  let score = 0;
  let questions = [];
  let timer = null;

  function startTrivia() {
    //show spinner
    questionIndex = 0;
    questions = [];
    score = 0;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      //get questions from server
      mainScreen.classList.add("hidden");
      howToPlayScreen.classList.add("hidden");
      resultScreen.classList.add("hidden");
      triviaScreen.classList.remove("hidden");

      questions = [{
          answers: ["Roma", "Athens", "London", "Japan"],
          correct: "Roma",
          image: "001"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma1", "Athens1", "London1", "Japan1"],
          correct: "Athens1",
          image: "002"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma2", "Athens2", "London2", "Japan2"],
          correct: "London2",
          image: "003"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma3", "Athens3", "London3", "Japan3"],
          correct: "London3",
          image: "004"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma4", "Athens4", "London4", "Japan4"],
          correct: "Athens4",
          image: "005"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma5", "Athens5", "London5", "Japan5"],
          correct: "Athens5",
          image: "006"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma6", "Athens6", "London6", "Japan6"],
          correct: "Roma6",
          image: "007"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma7", "Athens7", "London7", "Japan7"],
          correct: "Japan7",
          image: "008"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma8", "Athens8", "London8", "Japan8"],
          correct: "London8",
          image: "009"
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma9", "Athens9", "London9", "Japan9"],
          correct: "Japan9",
          image: "010"
        }
      ];

      const questionCount = document.getElementById("question-count");
      questionCount.innerHTML = questionLength.toString();
      displayNextQuestion();
    }, 50);
  }

  const isTriviaCompleted = function() {
    return questionLength === questionIndex;
  };

  function displayNextQuestion() {
    const answersContainer = document.getElementById("answers-container");
    const answerButtons = answersContainer.querySelectorAll(".default-button");

    answerButtons.forEach(function(element) {
      element.disabled = false;
      element.classList.remove("correct");
      element.classList.remove("wrong");
    });

    if (isTriviaCompleted()) {
      showScores();
    } else {
      startProgressbar();
      timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        guess(null);
      }, 10000);

      setQuizText("This is from");

      const imageElement = document.getElementById("question-placement");
      imageElement.src = `./assets/images/${questions[questionIndex].image}.png`;

      const choices = questions[questionIndex].answers;
      for (let i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        const element = document.getElementById(`answer${i}`);
        element.innerHTML = choices[i];

        element.addEventListener("click", handleAnswerClick);
      }

      showProgress();
    }
  }

  function handleAnswerClick(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget;
    const answer = el.innerHTML;
    el.removeEventListener("click", handleAnswerClick);
    guess(answer);
  }

  function showProgress() {
    const questionIndexElement = document.getElementById("question-index");
    const index = questionIndex + 1;
    questionIndexElement.innerHTML = index.toString();
  }

  function guess(answer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    const answersContainer = document.getElementById("answers-container");
    const answerButtons = answersContainer.querySelectorAll(".default-button");

    answerButtons.forEach((element) => {
      element.disabled = true;
      if (element.innerHTML === questions[questionIndex].correct) {
        element.classList.add("correct");
      }
    });

    stopProgressbar();

    if (questions[questionIndex].correct === answer) { // correct answer
      score++;
      setQuizText("Fantastic … Correct!");
    } else if (answer) { // incorrect answer
      setQuizText("Nice try … You were close.");
      answerButtons.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.innerHTML === answer) {
          element.classList.add("wrong");
        }
      });
    } else {
      setQuizText("Your time is out! Oh no!");
    }

    questionIndex++;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      displayNextQuestion();
    }, 2500);
  }

  function setQuizText(text) {
    const el = document.getElementById("trivia-text");
    el.innerHTML = text;
  }

  function showScores() {
    const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
    const scoreTotalElement = document.getElementById("score-total");
    const scoreNameElement = document.getElementById("score-name");

    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString();
    scoreTotalElement.innerHTML = questionLength.toString();

    if (score < 4) {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Newbie";
    } else if (score < 7) {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Rookie";
    } else if (score < 10) {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Expert";
    } else {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Grandmaster";
    }

    triviaScreen.classList.add("hidden");
    resultScreen.classList.remove("hidden");
  }

  function startProgressbar() {
    // select div turn into progressbar
    const progressbar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
    progressbar.innerHTML = "";
    // create div changes width show progress
    const progressbarInner = document.createElement("span");

    // Append progressbar to main progressbardiv
    progressbar.appendChild(progressbarInner);

    // When all set start animation
    progressbarInner.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  }

  function stopProgressbar() {
    const progressbar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
    const progressbarInner = progressbar.querySelector("span");
    progressbarInner.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  }
}());
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Verdana', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container {
  background: #999999;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.screen-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 20px 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.trivia-screen-step {
  color: #ccc;
}

.trivia-image-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.trivia-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.trivia-timer {
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 5px 6px;
}

.trivia-timer span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff, #06c);
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 3em;
  animation: progressbar-countdown;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes progressbar-countdown {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

.trivia-question {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.how-to-play-screen .default-button {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button-outer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.default-button {
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 3em;
  font-family: 'Verdana', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2.45px;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background .2s;
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.default-button:hover {
  background: #222;
}

.default-button[disabled] {
  background: transparent;
  color: #222;
  cursor: default;
}

.default-button[disabled]:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.default-button.correct {
  cursor: default;
  background: #2bb24a;
  color: #fff;
}

.default-button.correct:hover {
  background: #2bb24a;
  color: #fff;
}

.default-button.wrong {
  cursor: default;
  background: #F6484C;
  color: #fff;
}

.default-button.wrong:hover {
  background: #F6484C;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.text {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: none;
}

.trivia-logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.trivia-corner-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100px;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Verdana', cursive;
  font-size: 34px;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.close-button:hover {
  color: #eee;
}

.score-name {
  margin: 0 0 28px;
  font-size: 46px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .screen-section {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .button-outer {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="screen-section main-screen">
      <div class="trivia-image-wrapper">
        <img alt="LOGO" src="/assets/Game-Logo.png" class="trivia-image">
      </div>
      <h1>Trivia</h1>
      <div class="button-container">
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="play" type="button">Play</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="how-to-play-button" type="button">How to play?</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt="logo" src="/assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-section hidden how-to-play-screen">
      <img alt="LOGO" src="/assets/Game-Logo.png" class="trivia-corner-logo">
      <button class="close-button" id="close-how-to" type="button">x</button>
      <h2 class="title">How to Play</h2>
      <p>Answer questions to score points.</p>
      <button class="default-button" id="lets-start" type="button">Ok. Let's start</button>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt="logo" src="/assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-section hidden trivia-screen">
      <div class="trivia-screen-step"><span id="question-index">1</span> out of <span id="question-count">10</span></div>
      <div class="trivia-image-wrapper">
        <img alt="image" src="IMAGE-URL" class="trivia-image" id="question-placement">
      </div>
      <div class="trivia-timer" id="progress-bar"></div>
      <div class="trivia-question" id="trivia-text"></div>
      <div class="button-container" id="answers-container">
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer0" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer1" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer2" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer3" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt="logo" src="/assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-section hidden result-screen">
      <div class="trivia-image-wrapper">
        <img alt="Trivia LOGO" src="/assets/Game-Logo.png" class="trivia-image">
      </div>
      <p class="score"><span id="score">0</span> out of <span id="score-total">10</span></p>
      <h1 class="score-name" id="score-name">Trivia</h1>
      <span class="description">you will learn more.</span>
      <button class="default-button" id="play-again" type="button">Play again</button>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt=" logo" src="/assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `<img>` tag for a `<p>` tag and replace the image filenames inside the variable `questions` for your question text. Then change these 2 lines:

```py
      const imageElement = document.getElementById("question-placement");
      imageElement.src = `./assets/images/${questions[questionIndex].image}.png`;
```

for these 2 lines:

```py
      const textElement = document.getElementById("question-placement");
      textElement.innerHTML = questions[questionIndex].text;
```

Everything is pretty straightforward.

```js
(function() {
  const playButton = document.querySelector("#play");
  const letsstartButton = document.querySelector("#lets-start");
  const playagainButton = document.querySelector("#play-again");
  const howToPlayButton = document.querySelector("#how-to-play-button");
  const closeHowToButton = document.querySelector("#close-how-to");
  const howToPlayScreen = document.querySelector(".how-to-play-screen");
  const mainScreen = document.querySelector(".main-screen");
  const triviaScreen = document.querySelector(".trivia-screen");
  const resultScreen = document.querySelector(".result-screen");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", startTrivia);
  letsstartButton.addEventListener("click", startTrivia);
  playagainButton.addEventListener("click", startTrivia);

  howToPlayButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    howToPlayScreen.classList.remove("hidden");
    mainScreen.classList.add("hidden");
  });

  closeHowToButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    howToPlayScreen.classList.add("hidden");
    mainScreen.classList.remove("hidden");
  });

  const questionLength = 10;
  let questionIndex = 0;
  let score = 0;
  let questions = [];
  let timer = null;

  function startTrivia() {
    //show spinner
    questionIndex = 0;
    questions = [];
    score = 0;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      //get questions from server
      mainScreen.classList.add("hidden");
      howToPlayScreen.classList.add("hidden");
      resultScreen.classList.add("hidden");
      triviaScreen.classList.remove("hidden");

      questions = [{
          answers: ["Roma", "Athens", "London", "Japan"],
          correct: "Roma",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma1", "Athens1", "London1", "Japan1"],
          correct: "Athens1",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma2", "Athens2", "London2", "Japan2"],
          correct: "London2",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma3", "Athens3", "London3", "Japan3"],
          correct: "London3",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma4", "Athens4", "London4", "Japan4"],
          correct: "Athens4",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma5", "Athens5", "London5", "Japan5"],
          correct: "Athens5",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma6", "Athens6", "London6", "Japan6"],
          correct: "Roma6",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma7", "Athens7", "London7", "Japan7"],
          correct: "Japan7",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma8", "Athens8", "London8", "Japan8"],
          correct: "London8",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        },
        {
          answers: ["Roma9", "Athens9", "London9", "Japan9"],
          correct: "Japan9",
          text: "YOUR TEXT HERE."
        }
      ];

      const questionCount = document.getElementById("question-count");
      questionCount.innerHTML = questionLength.toString();
      displayNextQuestion();
    }, 50);
  }

  const isTriviaCompleted = function() {
    return questionLength === questionIndex;
  };

  function displayNextQuestion() {
    const answersContainer = document.getElementById("answers-container");
    const answerButtons = answersContainer.querySelectorAll(".default-button");

    answerButtons.forEach(function(element) {
      element.disabled = false;
      element.classList.remove("correct");
      element.classList.remove("wrong");
    });

    if (isTriviaCompleted()) {
      showScores();
    } else {
      startProgressbar();
      timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        guess(null);
      }, 10000);

      setQuizText("This is from");

      const textElement = document.getElementById("question-placement");
      textElement.innerHTML = questions[questionIndex].text;

      const choices = questions[questionIndex].answers;
      for (let i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        const element = document.getElementById(`answer${i}`);
        element.innerHTML = choices[i];

        element.addEventListener("click", handleAnswerClick);
      }

      showProgress();
    }
  }

  function handleAnswerClick(e) {
    const el = e.currentTarget;
    const answer = el.innerHTML;
    el.removeEventListener("click", handleAnswerClick);
    guess(answer);
  }

  function showProgress() {
    const questionIndexElement = document.getElementById("question-index");
    const index = questionIndex + 1;
    questionIndexElement.innerHTML = index.toString();
  }

  function guess(answer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    const answersContainer = document.getElementById("answers-container");
    const answerButtons = answersContainer.querySelectorAll(".default-button");

    answerButtons.forEach((element) => {
      element.disabled = true;
      if (element.innerHTML === questions[questionIndex].correct) {
        element.classList.add("correct");
      }
    });

    stopProgressbar();

    if (questions[questionIndex].correct === answer) { // correct answer
      score++;
      setQuizText("Fantastic … Correct!");
    } else if (answer) { // incorrect answer
      setQuizText("Nice try … You were close.");
      answerButtons.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.innerHTML === answer) {
          element.classList.add("wrong");
        }
      });
    } else {
      setQuizText("Your time is out! Oh no!");
    }

    questionIndex++;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      displayNextQuestion();
    }, 2500);
  }

  function setQuizText(text) {
    const el = document.getElementById("trivia-text");
    el.innerHTML = text;
  }

  function showScores() {
    const scoreElement = document.getElementById("score");
    const scoreTotalElement = document.getElementById("score-total");
    const scoreNameElement = document.getElementById("score-name");

    scoreElement.innerHTML = score.toString();
    scoreTotalElement.innerHTML = questionLength.toString();

    if (score < 4) {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Newbie";
    } else if (score < 7) {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Rookie";
    } else if (score < 10) {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Expert";
    } else {
      scoreNameElement.innerHTML = "Grandmaster";
    }

    triviaScreen.classList.add("hidden");
    resultScreen.classList.remove("hidden");
  }

  function startProgressbar() {
    // select div turn into progressbar
    const progressbar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
    progressbar.innerHTML = "";
    // create div changes width show progress
    const progressbarInner = document.createElement("span");

    // Append progressbar to main progressbardiv
    progressbar.appendChild(progressbarInner);

    // When all set start animation
    progressbarInner.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  }

  function stopProgressbar() {
    const progressbar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
    const progressbarInner = progressbar.querySelector("span");
    progressbarInner.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  }
}());
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Verdana', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container {
  background: #999999;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.screen-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 20px 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.trivia-screen-step {
  color: #ccc;
}

.trivia-image-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.trivia-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.trivia-timer {
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 5px 6px;
}

.trivia-timer span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff, #06c);
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 3em;
  animation: progressbar-countdown;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes progressbar-countdown {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}

.trivia-question {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.how-to-play-screen .default-button {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button-outer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.default-button {
  background: #333333;
  border-radius: 3em;
  font-family: 'Verdana', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2.45px;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: background .2s;
  outline: none;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.default-button:hover {
  background: #222;
}

.default-button[disabled] {
  background: transparent;
  color: #222;
  cursor: default;
}

.default-button[disabled]:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.default-button.correct {
  cursor: default;
  background: #2bb24a;
  color: #fff;
}

.default-button.correct:hover {
  background: #2bb24a;
  color: #fff;
}

.default-button.wrong {
  cursor: default;
  background: #F6484C;
  color: #fff;
}

.default-button.wrong:hover {
  background: #F6484C;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.text {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: none;
}

.trivia-logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.trivia-corner-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100px;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Verdana', cursive;
  font-size: 34px;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.close-button:hover {
  color: #eee;
}

.score-name {
  margin: 0 0 28px;
  font-size: 46px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .screen-section {
    padding: 50px;
  }
  .button-outer {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="screen-section main-screen">
      <div class="trivia-image-wrapper">
        <img alt="LOGO" src="./assets/Game-Logo.png" class="trivia-image">
      </div>
      <h1>Trivia</h1>
      <div class="button-container">
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="play" type="button">Play</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="how-to-play-button" type="button">How to play?</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt="logo" src="./assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-section hidden how-to-play-screen">
      <img alt="LOGO" src="./assets/Game-Logo.png" class="trivia-corner-logo">
      <button class="close-button" id="close-how-to" type="button">X</button>
      <h2 class="title">How to Play</h2>
      <p>Answer questions to score points.</p>
      <button class="default-button" id="lets-start" type="button">Ok. Let's start</button>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt="logo" src="./assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-section hidden trivia-screen">
      <div class="trivia-screen-step"><span id="question-index">1</span> out of <span id="question-count">10</span></div>
      <div class="trivia-image-wrapper">
      <p id="question-placement"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="trivia-timer" id="progress-bar"></div>
      <div class="trivia-question" id="trivia-text"></div>
      <div class="button-container" id="answers-container">
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer0" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer1" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer2" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-outer">
          <button class="default-button" id="answer3" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt="logo" src="./assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen-section hidden result-screen">
      <div class="trivia-image-wrapper">
        <img alt="Trivia LOGO" src="./assets/Game-Logo.png" class="trivia-image">
      </div>
      <p class="score"><span id="score">0</span> out of <span id="score-total">10</span></p>
      <h1 class="score-name" id="score-name">Trivia</h1>
      <span class="description">you will learn more.</span>
      <button class="default-button" id="play-again" type="button">Play again</button>
      <div class="trivia-logo">
        <img alt=" logo" src="./assets/-Logo.png">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will accept the answer as correct. I will create another question, since I want a script to choose randomly questions, and a specific number of them (same trivia). I hope you can assist further.

Comment: Joan Lara, you can also visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088037/random-questions-order-when-game-starts-trivia-javascript-game